# Uploading images from a url naming dilemma

Tags: php, image, upload

Let's say I have an image URL

http://website.com/content/image.png

I want to grab that image and place it in my own server, but I want to rename it beforehand so I can store the location in the database.

I am using the following code:

```
$url = 'http://website.com/content/image.png';
/* Extract the filename */
$filename = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
/* Save file wherever you want */
file_put_contents('upload/'.$filename, file_get_contents($url));
```

If I want to rename the file to something entirely new, but keep the extension in tact, how can I accomplish that? Also will this work if there is more content in the url?

For example instead of:
url here/content/image.png
It would be:
url here/content/stuff/images/image.png

I am basically trying to write a universal function that will take a URL to an image, upload it to my server, and rename that image to what I want while keeping the extension in tact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First- You need to check if your webserver can access URL's from another server.

Second- Assuming you can:

```
$url = 'http://website.com/content/image.png';
$extension = end(explode(".", $url));
$filename = "the_filename_you_want.".$extension;
file_put_contents('upload/'.$filename, file_get_contents($url));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 $url = 'http://www.bla.org/img/derp.jpg';
 $extension = end(explode('.', $url));
 file_put_contents('/tmp/image.'.$extension, file_get_contents($url));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$filename = substr($url, strrpos($url, '.'));`

Answer (score 0):

You need [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
$url = 'http://website.com/content/image.png';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
/* Extract the filename and extension */
$filename = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
/* Save file wherever you want */
file_put_contents('upload/' . $filename . '.' . $extension, file_get_contents($url));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at `parse_url()` function to get at the various URL components.

Like:

```
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
$uri = $url_parts['path'];
```

Then use `pathinfo()` to break up the components of the URI into path, filename, extension, etc.

```
$uri_info = pathinfo($uri);
$dir_name = $uri_info['dirname'];
$file_name = $uri_info['filename'];
$file_basename = $uri_info['basename'];
$file_extension = $uri_info['extension'];
```